# is there a way of viewing just text from tinymce yii?

Tags: php, yii, tinymce

Whenever I use the yii extension tinymce, after saving my input it turns into codes. For example if I type "sample text" it'll display as

```
<p>&nbsp;sample text</p>
```

I was wondering if it's possible to view it from the admin as just plain text....

Can anyone help?

This is the tinymce
[image]

When I save this it would look like this, this is what I want to change if it is possible.

[image]

to print this out I use this code:

```
<h3 class="header">     <?php
if (!$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')) {
echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db('hygeia_master', $link)) {
echo 'Could not select database';
exit;
}

$sql    = 'SELECT title FROM about_histback order by datetime desc limit 1';
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['title']."<br>";
}


?>
    <span class="header-line"></span> 
    </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">        

    <div class="span6">
    <?php
if (!$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')) {
echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db('hygeia_master', $link)) {
echo 'Could not select database';
exit;
}

$sql    = 'SELECT historical_background FROM about_histback order by        datetime desc limit 1';
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['historical_background']."<br>";
}


?>
</div>
```

so the display would look like this[image]

Comment: Show us what you have so far, where you print it out and how you received the data.

Comment: It looks fine from where I print it out. I just wanted the admin side to printout the same way instead of displaying codes. I've updated the question

Comment: Can you not just `strip_tags()` where you're displaying it in the admin?

Comment: I'm not sure... I haven't tried that before... can you possibly try to show me how to do that in yii?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDetailView has a type param for each attributes:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        // First example
        'fieldName:raw', // raw: the attribute value will not be changed at all.
        // Second example
        'fieldName:text', //text: the attribute value will be HTML-encoded when rendering.
        // Third example
        'fieldName:html', // html: the attribute value will be purified and then returned.
        // Fourth example
        array(
            'name' => 'fieldName',
            'type' => 'ntext', // ntext: the formatNtext method will be called to format the attribute value as a HTML-encoded plain text with newlines converted as the HTML <br /> or <p></p> tags.
        ),
    ),
));
```

More details you cand find in [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDetailView#attributes-detail), other lists also supports output types.